# D3 chart, adding more info to the one the chart brings by default

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am using [this bubble chart from D3](http://bl.ocks.org/phuonghuynh/54a2f97950feadb45b07) and I want to know how to play with some more data.

Here is the object which contains the data

```
data: {
  items: [
    {text: "Java", count: "236"},
    {text: ".Net", count: "382"},
    {text: "Php", count: "170"},
    {text: "Ruby", count: "123"},
    {text: "D", count: "12"},
    {text: "Python", count: "170"},
    {text: "C/C++", count: "382"},
    {text: "Pascal", count: "10"},
    {text: "Something", count: "170"},
  ],
  eval: function (item) {return item.count;},
  classed: function (item) {return item.text.split(" ").join("");}
},
```

I will like to add more properties in every object in that array, like this

```
data: {
  items: [
    {text: "Java", count: "236", phone: "32424234", email: "theemail@mail.com"},
    {text: ".Net", count: "382", phone: "32424234", email: "theemail@mail.com"},
    {text: "Php", count: "170", phone: "32424234", email: "theemail@mail.com"},
    {text: "Ruby", count: "123", phone: "32424234", email: "theemail@mail.com"},
    {text: "D", count: "12", phone: "32424234", email: "theemail@mail.com"},
    {text: "Python", count: "170", phone: "32424234", email: "theemail@mail.com"},
    {text: "C/C++", count: "382", phone: "32424234", email: "theemail@mail.com"},
    {text: "Pascal", count: "10", phone: "32424234", email: "theemail@mail.com"},
    {text: "Something", count: "170", phone: "32424234", email: "theemail@mail.com"},
  ],
  eval: function (item) {return item.count;},
  classed: function (item) {return item.text.split(" ").join("");}
},
```

as you see that chart has a `centralClick` method where I am calling an alert `alert("Here is more details!!");`, instead of that alert I will like to display phone and email properties instead. Because those properties should be hidden until the user clicks in the bubble.

If you want to see the full code and not going to the link I pasted above, then here is

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Hello Bubble Chart</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <!-- scrips needed -->
  <style>
    .bubbleChart {
      min-width: 100px;
      max-width: 700px;
      height: 700px;
      margin: 0 auto;
    }
    .bubbleChart svg{
      background: #000000;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body style="background: #000000">
<div class="bubbleChart"/>
</body>
</html>
index.js#

$(document).ready(function () {
  var bubbleChart = new d3.svg.BubbleChart({
    supportResponsive: true,
    //container: => use @default
    size: 600,
    //viewBoxSize: => use @default
    innerRadius: 600 / 3.5,
    //outerRadius: => use @default
    radiusMin: 50,
    //radiusMax: use @default
    //intersectDelta: use @default
    //intersectInc: use @default
    //circleColor: use @default
    data: {
      items: [
        {text: "Java", count: "236"},
        {text: ".Net", count: "382"},
        {text: "Php", count: "170"},
        {text: "Ruby", count: "123"},
        {text: "D", count: "12"},
        {text: "Python", count: "170"},
        {text: "C/C++", count: "382"},
        {text: "Pascal", count: "10"},
        {text: "Something", count: "170"},
      ],
      eval: function (item) {return item.count;},
      classed: function (item) {return item.text.split(" ").join("");}
    },
    plugins: [
      {
        name: "central-click",
        options: {
          text: "(See more detail)",
          style: {
            "font-size": "12px",
            "font-style": "italic",
            "font-family": "Source Sans Pro, sans-serif",
            //"font-weight": "700",
            "text-anchor": "middle",
            "fill": "white"
          },
          attr: {dy: "65px"},
          centralClick: function() {
            alert("Here is more details!!");
          }
        }
      },
      {
        name: "lines",
        options: {
          format: [
            {// Line #0
              textField: "count",
              classed: {count: true},
              style: {
                "font-size": "28px",
                "font-family": "Source Sans Pro, sans-serif",
                "text-anchor": "middle",
                fill: "white"
              },
              attr: {
                dy: "0px",
                x: function (d) {return d.cx;},
                y: function (d) {return d.cy;}
              }
            },
            {// Line #1
              textField: "text",
              classed: {text: true},
              style: {
                "font-size": "14px",
                "font-family": "Source Sans Pro, sans-serif",
                "text-anchor": "middle",
                fill: "white"
              },
              attr: {
                dy: "20px",
                x: function (d) {return d.cx;},
                y: function (d) {return d.cy;}
              }
            }
          ],
          centralFormat: [
            {// Line #0
              style: {"font-size": "50px"},
              attr: {}
            },
            {// Line #1
              style: {"font-size": "30px"},
              attr: {dy: "40px"}
            }
          ]
        }
      }]
  });
});
```

so, what should I do in order to achieve what I need ?

Answer (score 0):

You need not import the javascript into your HTML

```
<script src="http://phuonghuynh.github.io/js/bower_components/bubble-chart/src/plugins/lines/lines.js"></script>
```

**Reason** this handles the click event for you you will need to override it.

Instead you write your own custom click event handler which will give you the node data like this:

```
  d3.svg.BubbleChart.define("central-click", function(options) {
    var self = this;

    self.setup = (function(node) {
      var original = self.setup;
      return function(node) {
        var fn = original.apply(this, arguments);
        self.event.on("click", function(node) {
          //here you will get the data you want
          console.log(node.data()[0].item)
        });
        return fn;
      };
    })();

    self.reset = (function(node) {
      var original = self.reset;
      return function(node) {
        var fn = original.apply(this, arguments);
        node.select("text.central-click").remove();
        return fn;
      };
    })();

    self.moveToCentral = (function(node) {
      var original = self.moveToCentral;
      return function(node) {
        var fn = original.apply(this, arguments);
        var transition = self.getTransition().centralNode;
        transition.each("end", function() {
          node.append("text").classed({
              "central-click": true
            })
            .attr(options.attr)
            .style(options.style)
            .attr("x", function(d) {
              return d.cx;
            })
            .attr("y", function(d) {
              return d.cy;
            })
            .text(options.text)
            .style("opacity", 0).transition().duration(self.getOptions().transitDuration / 2).style("opacity", "0.8");
        });
        return fn;
      };
    })();
  });
```

Check my working code [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/ASC7NbsAezGt60UvAEjH?p=preview) on click of a node it will console its data.

Hope this helps!